# Emoji unicode in Bash prints as characters not emoji itself

Tags: bash, unicode, scripting

From the [emoji list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html) I chose India flag unicode:

```
U+1F1EE 
U+1F1F3
```

I wanted to add it to my PS1.

But whenever I try something as follows, it prints out as IN only not the flag emoji.

[image: PS1_1]

But when I copy from the terminal and paste it here, it works.

```
$ printf '\U1F1EE\U1F1F3\n'
```

How to get it worked on the bash terminal?.

Comment: The font your terminal uses may not have the characters necessary, so the terminal displays representations of the two characters individually.

Comment: When two Regional Indicator characters are inserted in sequence, certain pairs automatically create a grapheme cluster **on supported platforms**. See https://emojipedia.org/emoji-sequence/

Comment: I am using the ubuntu mono bold font. It does not support?.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash 4.2 or later, you could try something like:

```sh
PS1=$'\U1F1EE\U1F1F3\n'
```

Comment: the thing here is the unsupported font. As you can see the terminal displays `IN` which is the regional indicator represented by the above 2 characters

Comment: I am using the ubuntu mono bold font. It does not support?.

Comment: I don't have ubuntu to test. Have you tried it?